# nester attributes for has_many are not shown if the form fails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, associations

If form fails validation, fields for has_many association, disappears from view:

my new action looks like

```
def new
  @realty = Realty.new
  @realty.build_user
  @realty.build_address
  #user, address are has_one association, and they stay in view after failed validation
  6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } # and this one vanishes away 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @realty }
  end
end
```

if I add to my form this snippet

```
-  if @realty.realty_images.empty?
  - 6.times { @realty.realty_images.build }
```

fields are shown up again, but it is a little rough

I tried

```
6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } if @realty.realty_images.empty?
```

or

```
6.times { @realty.realty_images.build }
6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } if @realty.realty_images.empty?
```

in controller, but it doesn't works, and fields disappears again on failed validation.

create action:

```
def create
    @realty = Realty.new(params[:realty]) 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @realty.save
        format.html { redirect_to @realty, notice: 'Realty was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @realty, status: :created, location: @realty }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @realty.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end
```

my -form

```
= simple_form_for(@realty) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :offer_type
    = f.input :realty_type
    = f.input :rent_type
    = f.input :price
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :state, as: :hidden
    = f.input :number_of_rooms
    = f.input :floor
    = f.input :service, as: :hidden
    = f.simple_fields_for :address do |address_f|
      = address_f.input :city, :required => true
      = address_f.input :state, :required => true
      = address_f.input :street, :required => true
    - unless user_signed_in?
      = f.simple_fields_for :user do |user_f|  
        = user_f.input :name, :autofocus => true, :required => true
        = user_f.input :phone, :required => true
        = user_f.input :email, :required => true
        = user_f.input :password, :required => true
        = user_f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true
    -  if @realty.realty_images.empty?
      - 6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } 
    = f.simple_fields_for :realty_images do |image_f|
      = image_f.input :image, as: :file

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

realty model

```
class Realty < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :floor, :user_id, :number_of_rooms, :price, :service, :state, :realty_images_attributes, :address_attributes, :user_attributes, :offer_type, :realty_type, :rent_type

  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :realty_images, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :address, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :offer_type, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 1..256 }
  validates :realty_type, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 1..256 }
  validates :state, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 1..256 }
  validates :description, :length => { :maximum => 2000 }
  validates :service, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 1..256 }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :realty_images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Comment: Please show #create, that's the key.

Comment: I add it to my question. But it is pretty standard  :)

Comment: Seems not good. You don't have logic to save users, address and images in create?

Comment: I deleted this snipped "@realty.user = current_user if user_signed_in?" because it isn't necessary in this question. In fact fields for address and user after failed validation, are present, and create action, if validation passed, creates all that is necessary. I will write test for this later, because it is a little new for me, but I debug it in rails console, and realty.user, realty.address shows valid user and address

Comment: user should never be set like that in #new. It should be used in #create like `@realty = current_user.realty.build. Beside, user is not the main problem, I meant how do you save address, images? They are in another model and not attributes of Realty. I would like to write some code but there are too much to write and I don't know the details as well. I suggest you to sit back to organize the main logics and then ask specific question later. Sorry for not being able to help.

Comment: The idea is to create user with new realty. For example If I am an new user, a can create account with new realty for sale. I Add my form to quiesion

Comment: You said "#user, address are has_one association" which means they are other models. But the form is for Realty model while containing address and user info. How can that be saved? That's why I said there are lots of work to change.

Comment: Take a look at realty model a have added

Comment: It has                                        accepts_nested_attributes_for :realty_images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

Comment: Sorry I dont want to argue with you. The issue is in disappearance of associated fields, not in permission to save. As I sad before, all associations are saved if they dont fail validation, if they fails validation, image fields disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing two actions: new and create. The "new" action is invoked only when accessing the blank form at /realties/new. And the "create" action is invoked when submitting the form.

You add 6 sample images only in "new" action. In create action, `Realty.new` will discard images that are blank (not filled in). This is why you will see them disappear. You will need to re-add them on validation error. You could extract the common setup into a method:

```
class RealtiesController
  def new
    @realty = Realty.new
    @realty.populate
  end

  def create
    @realty = Realty.new(params[:realty])
    if @realty.save
      # ...
    else
      @realty.populate
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end

class Realty
  # you could also place it in the controller
  # if you feel it fits better there
  def populate
    6.times{ self.realty_images.build }
  end
end
```

Comment: It is typically the same, but more elegant approach.This works, but validations errors related to realty_images form fields, don't show up :(

Comment: Yes, they are separate from main model (realty). You have to get and show realty_image.errors for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the failed object still present in #new, you can just avoid creating a new one if old one existed. Like this:

```
@realty = || Realty.new
```

This way #new will use the old failed object instead of the new.

For @realty object, it will work. But for further associations such as user and address, I have not done similar things before so you need to verify it by yourself.

*p.s The code relies on the instant variable that's why I'm concerned how the obj is saved. Hope this could be of a little help :)*

Comment: You mean @realty ||= Realty.new ? That doesn't solve the issue. I have problem only with accepts_nested_attributes_for :realty_images fields, they disappear after failed validation, all other fields stay there. Thank you for your help. I've deploy app to my VPS, you may take a look here http://www.andryas.info

Comment: @AndreyYasinishyn, I don't have similar case before. But I think the solution is to use an instance of image to build the form, and reserve this instance untouched and delivered to #new if #create failed.

Comment: What do you mean? How to implement this?

Comment: Maybe use my rough approach in view " 6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } if @realty.realty_images.empty?
  and forget it like a bad dream?

Comment: do you mean like this                                            `def create
   .......
      if @realty.save
        .....
      else
        6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } if @realty.realty_images.empty?
        .......
      end
    end
  end`      In principle, this solved the problem. Add it as a answer please

Comment: Nice you figured it out :) I meant carrying the object, not sure if they are same. You can add your own detailed answer if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Billy Chan Thank you for your advice, you really help me. My solution of this issue, is a little rough but it works well

in create action a add

```
6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } if @realty.realty_images.empty?
```

if @realty.save return false

it looks like this

```
 def create
    @realty = Realty.new(params[:realty]) 
    @realty.user = current_user if user_signed_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @realty.save
        format.html { redirect_to @realty, notice: 'Realty was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @realty, status: :created, location: @realty }
      else
        6.times { @realty.realty_images.build } if @realty.realty_images.empty?
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @realty.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```