# validate count of created has_many objects in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Validate count of created has_many objects in rails 3.2?

I need a custom validation for "max/min" count of associated object.
I have Realty, that has

```
has_many :realty_images, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :realty_images
```

and realty_image:

```
class RealtyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :image, :realty_id
  belongs_to :realty

  #here a suppose I need to put some kind of custom validation
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard validation methods work well with associations:

```
class Ad
  has_many :realty_images

  # make sure there are some images
  validates_presence_of :realty_images

  # or make sure the number of images is in certain range
  validates_length_of :realty_images, within: 5..10
end
```

Check out [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_length_of) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know about the existence of such. this works great to.

Comment: **@Semyon Perepelitsa** Can you please tell me why this is happening [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413271/nester-attributes-for-has-many-are-not-shown-if-the-form-fails-validation?)

Comment: Sure, I've answered it too. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I totally understood, but if you try to limit the number of realty_images of a given realty, and assuming that realty.maximum contains the max limit for that given realty:

In RealtyImage model:

```
class RealtyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :image, :realty_id
  belongs_to :realty

  validate :maximum_number_of_realty_images
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  protected
  def maximum_number_of_realty_images
    errors.add(:base, "Maximum reached") unless realty.realty_images.count < realty.maximum
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you tell one more thing, I'm not sure, it "validate" or "validates"??., and :base it's mean that error will pop-out in the top as base notice< or for particular field

Comment: @AndreyYasinishyn it is 'validate' for registering a custom validator, 'validates' for Rails predefined. Regarding the error, as it is added to the 'base' is connected to the Model as a whole, not for a specific attribute; so you can check it at realty_image.errors

Comment: I gen an error using this approach: realty_image.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
  validate :maximum_number_of_realty_images(10)

Comment: I don't think that symbol can receive arguments like :symbol(arg). But if I try `validate maximum_number_of_realty_images(10)` I get **undefined method `maximum_number_of_realty_images'**

Comment: try validate :maximum_number_of_realty_images, 10

Comment: Now it passes validation even if model is invalid

Comment: On other hand your approach helped me to make min validator, But I put it in mu realty class instead. `validate :maximum_number_of_realty_images
  def maximum_number_of_realty_images
    errors.add(:base, "You need to add at least 1 photo") if self.realty_images.empty?
  end `

Comment: I have edited my answer; the simpler way is to add a maximum (and minimum if needed) attribute to the Realty model. Makes sense for your app?

Comment: Thank you Galen, but it works only when it is in realty class.